# UIButton background won't be transparent

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, uibutton

I'm trying to create a custom UIButton, but when I set the background to be clear/transparent, it fills the background of the frame with black. I'm not creating these in IB, I need to do this programmatically. Is there something I'm missing?

```
UIButton* btn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeCustom];
btn.frame = rect;
[btn addTarget: self action:@selector(toggleMaster) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
btn.opaque = NO;
btn.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
[btn setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@_icon", self.currentKey]] forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[self addSubview: btn];
```

EDIT:
I realized I should mention I am doing this in the  `drawRect` method of UIView. Bad practice?

Comment: i dont see anything wrong. may the image you used has black background. did you try using different image?

Comment: I have pasted your code . Its working fine.Just see whether you are setting valid bg image at the line :[btn setBackgroundImage: [UIImage imageNamed: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@_icon", self.currentKey]] forState: UIControlStateNormal]; or give some hardcoded image there.

Comment: Could it have to do with this being done in the drawRect method?

Comment: can you paste your drawrect code?

Comment: I just switched it to the init method and commented out `drawRect`. I guess drawing methods are not meant for buttons

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to set the `backgroundColor`, `UIButtonTypeCustom` is already transparent by default. Did you try without it? Also, is the image transparent? The size is the same of the button?

Comment: I've already tried that. It continues to make a black background. The PNG already has a transparent background. It has rounded corners which is where the black bg is exposed